# How do I change a device's currently active backup transport?

Tags: adb, android-backup-service

When I execute the `bmgr list transports` command in the adb shell with my Android device plugged in, I see the following three backup transports are available for my Android device:

```
    com.android.localtransport/.LocalTransport
    com.google.android.gms/.backup.migrate.service.D2dTransport
  * com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService
```

I understand that the `*` character identifies the currently active transport.

I would like to change the currently active transport to `com.google.android.gms/.backup.migrate.service.D2dTransport`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following command in the adb shell whilst your device is plugged in:

```shell
bmgr transport com.google.android.gms/.backup.migrate.service.D2dTransport
```

Now when you run `bmgr list transports`, you will see the following output:

```shell
    com.android.localtransport/.LocalTransport
  * com.google.android.gms/.backup.migrate.service.D2dTransport
    com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService
```

To get a better understanding of the [bmgr](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bmgr) shell tool, just run `bmgr` in the adb shell with no arguments and you'll see usage guidance.

Comment: Your example selected a different transport than in the output. To select the D2dTransport: bmgr transport com.google.android.gms/.backup.migrate.service.D2dTransport

Comment: @GerbenVersluis: Thank you for calling this out. I've corrected my answer.